Can not access parameters in controller class constructor
When I try to set a class property from the parameterBag in the class constructor, like so:
public function __construct()
{
    $this->foo = $this->getParameter('app.foo');
}

I get
Call to a member function has() on null

I wonder if it's possible to access parameters defined in config/services.yaml in the constructor of a controller ?

You can use the #[Autowire] attribute
public function __construct(#[Autowire(param: 'app.foo')] private readonly string $foo)
{
}

Symfony documentation

Nice, I wans't aware of this solution for "non-autowireable arguments". Pretty clean syntaxe speacially if you already use attributes.

A Symfony controller can access the container (which is used to gather the parameters), but not in the constructor. As you can see in the dumped container, the controller class is instantiated first, and the controller is only set afterwards through a setContainer method.
If you don't want to use the Autowire attribute (for example when you don't know yet which parameters to access), as recommended by Artem, you can still call $this->getParameter() anywhere later in your controller class - just not in the constructor. If you need the whole bag of parameters in the constructor, you can use the following code:
public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ContainerBagInterface $containerBag) {
  $this->foo = $containerBag->get('app.foo');
}

